# How to add a menu from a jQuery script file in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dom, navigation

I need to put in a menu from a script file so that I can only need to make changes in one place to reflect across the project.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var str = "<h3>Menu</h3><ul class='nav vertical-nav'>";
    str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=1' ></i>Chair</a></li>");
    str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=3' ></i>Secretary</a></li>");
    str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=2' ></i>Treasurer</a></li>");
    str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=4' ></i>Admin</a></li>");
    str.append("</ul>");

    $('#insert-menu').html(str);

});
```

Now the above example is purely appending strings, which does not work.
I am new to jquery, so I am learning about the `DOM` to achieve this.

Now I can find documentation on inserting html files, but not really a lot on how to add code directly.

When I do the `<h3>` tag by itself it works, but when I start adding attributes (I think) that is where the problem lies.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: the thing is you cannot get php to dynamically run it is interpreted on runtime

Comment: But the file in which I am importing this script passes down the variable from the php - so should that not cover it?

Comment: no, never used, but php is done with the page rendering it and you pass it dynamically :/

Comment: Cool thanks - I will look into it when I improve the code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `.append`, you need a jQuery object.

`var str = "<h3>Menu</h3><ul class='nav vertical-nav'>";` is a string.

Use `var str = $("<h3>Menu</h3><ul class='nav vertical-nav'>");` instead.

Comment: On a side note, you can also use `str.appendTo('#insert-menu');`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this with DOM elements

```
var menu = $("<ul>");
var item1 = $("<li>").append($("<a>").prop("href","?p=1")).text("Item 1"); 
var item2 = $("<li>").append($("<a>").prop("href","?p=2")).text("Item 2"); //..so on
//..so on
menu.append(item1).append(item2);
$('#insert-menu').append(menu);
//..so on
```

lets you avoid HTML errors for one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var str = "<h3>Menu</h3><ul class='nav vertical-nav'>";
    str+="<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=1' ></i>Chair</a></li>";
    str+="<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=3' ></i>Secretary</a></li>";
    str+="<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=2' ></i>Treasurer</a></li>";
    str+="<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=4' ></i>Admin</a></li>";
    str+="</ul>";

    $('#insert-menu').html(str);

});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var str = $("<h3>Menu</h3><ul class='nav vertical-nav'>");
    str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=1' ></i>Chair</a></li>");
     str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=3' ></i>Secretary</a></li>");
     str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=2' ></i>Treasurer</a></li>");
     str.append("<li><a href='staff_home.php?var01=<?php echo $userVar; ?>&var02=4' ></i>Admin</a></li>");
     str.append("</ul>");

    $('#insert-menu').html(str);

});
```